# OneLogin OIDC access and refresh tokens from expired sessions will continue to work (assuming unexpired tokens)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, onelogin

If an application obtained access or refresh tokens from a OneLogin session that has expired, and if those tokens have not expired, can the application continue using those tokens until they expire, or will user authentication be required to create a new OneLogin session?

So far I've been unable to find any oauth2 documentation describing this behavior clearly, but from what I've found it sounds like token expirations are entirely separate from IDP session expiration.

Answer (score 0):

The access token can by default be used and trusted any client/API until the tokens expire. Even if you have signed out or if your session has expired, that's why its good to keep the access token lifetime relatively short.

The clients can try to use the refresh token to get a new access token, but the identity provider will block those attempts if the user session is expired or signed out.

Comment: Interestingly OneLogin support says that the refresh token can be used even if the user's OneLogin session has expired

Comment: Different providers implement this differently, it is also a matter of which session we are talking about. For example, if you login and give Twitter access to Facebook, your cookie session will of course eventually expire, while the tokens can be used forever, until revoked.